# Salesforce Lightning Apps and Licensing

Tags: lightning-apps, licenses

I'm trying to navigate the extensive Salesforce licensing grid. My question revolves around external Lightning applications and user licenses. If I wanted to set up a Lightning application that runs external users through a survey workflow, say just a series of questions that saves information to objects, does each person who uses the survey need a license? Lightning apps seem like a great platform for such applications (rather than creating an entire website server stack), but if licensing gets complicated that makes the platform seem less feasible. If I want the survey to collect data from 100,000 people the costs would add up quickly.

Any guidance or links to licensing information would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: This may end up being a misunderstanding of Lightning Apps - apparently they are not necessarily intended for external "on the internet" web pages, but meant more for internal to Salesforce web pages. If anyone knows of any different opinions, please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this question eons ago, I've learned more about the Lightning framework. Lightning Components can be used internally to Salesforce, but they can also be used for publicly facing Community sites available to external users.